# In ext grid with buffered rendering, how to locate using scroll position?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am not getting the grid row index, so i am not able to use the buffered rendering plugin method of scrollto() .On using scroll position, the grid data is not fetched since the buffered rendering plugin doesn't get information that the grids scroll position has been changed, So my grid becomes blank and on physically scrolling the grid fetches data.
Please suggest some way to load the grid data using scroll position.
Here is the code:

```
 /*Created a grid with buffered rendering*/
  var LPanel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }],
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'bufferedrenderer',
            trailingBufferZone: 10, 
            leadingBufferZone: 10
        },
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        text: 'Click to scroll to specified scroll position',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            click: function () {
               /*On clicking the button, we will scroll the grid to a specified position*/
                var LProcessGGridView = LPanel.getView();
                var LPGGRidViewEle = LProcessGGridView.getEl();
                var LScrollbarPos = LPGGRidViewEle.getScrollTop();
                /*The actual position for scrolling will be calculated on the basis of an id*/
                LPGGRidViewEle.scroll('top', LScrollbarPos );
            }
        }
    })
```

On scrolling, the grid becomes blank and after scrolling manually, proper data is loaded.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  We need to see code you've attempted.  Please read this article: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: I think the problem is that http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-scrollTo doesnt fire any scroll(end/start) events. I guess you can try to fire it manually. As other option you can try to calculate store page number based on desired scroll postition and load that page instead of scrolling to it.